# Permission to selective calendar events

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-calendar, events

I want to set permission for calendar events based on certain column value. Users should view selected events based on their permission. How should i do it ?

Comment: please specify what environment you have?

Comment: Sharepoint 2010

Comment: Using code, workflow or manually?

Comment: anything would be okay for me

Answer (score 1):

If you can use custom solution then please refer the following steps

- Create a custom SharePoint solution
- Create an Event Receiver with ***ItemAdded*** and ***ItemUpdated*** event
- In the event handling use [BreakRoleInheritance](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/313effab-a5af-4fda-b39c-37f620fe95f2/itembreakroleinheritancetrue-vs-itembreakroleinheritancefalse?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)(false) function
- Now set the custom permission which you want over the item created
  and iten updated

The problem which might be exists here is the item may behave improper as if the user creates an item with the column value which he/she does not have permission then he/she may get error page once page is refreshed after adding item.

Let me know if i guess your problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link:
http://spcycle.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html

It will show you how to set item permission manually and using workflow.